# Safe operating area vs characteristics

Tags: transistors

I just started digging deeper into power electronics and came across the "Safe Operating Area" (or SOA) of a transistor/MOSFET.
One crucial thing I do not understand about this is how it uses the same graph as the better known transistor characteristics curve (Ic on y-axis and Vce on x-axis) but looks completely different. I can't wrap my head around this, how can two plots with the same axis' of the same device look so different?

To better show what I mean, here's the characteristics curve:

[image: transistor_characteristics_curve]

And here's the SOA curve:
[image: SOA_Curve]

Comment: The two graphs you have shown are unrelated. I mean, they're not even from the same data sheet so, what would you expect? If they were from the same data sheet then their respective uses are totally different and, again, why would you expect any clear compatibility? One graph is for an NPN transistor of unspecified type and the other is for a PNP transistor.

Comment: Neither of these are for MOSFETs, though you do see similar graphs for FETs. FETs don't exhibit second breakdown, though.

Comment: You can add "SOA" (powers for some "conditions" of use, PWM, ...) in the first graph for that transistor. Just plot the value of Vce*Ic which is the power dissipated (hyperboloid when linear axes are used, straight lines when logarithmic axes).)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These show two related, but completely different characteristics of the transistor.

The Ic/Vce graph shows the collector current as a function of the collector-emitter voltage for a given base current. It tells you how the transistor will behave in a circuit. In this graph, Vce is the free variable, and Ic depends on Vce. If you "plug" a certain Vce (and Ib) into this graph, you get the corresponding Ic. In other words, this graph depicts the function Ic=f(Vce, Ib).

The SOA plot, however, has *two* independent variables: Vce *and* Ic. Ic does not depend on Vce in this plot. Instead, you can view this plot as a function Safe=f(Vce, Ic), which takes on the values "1" (shaded area) and "0" (unshaded area). "1" means that the transistor survives (operating it under these conditions is safe), and "0" means that the transistor breaks under these operating conditions.

As an example, let's look at Vce=50V, Ic=2A. This is within the shaded area of the SOA plot, so the transistor is guaranteed to survive this with enough cooling. However, Vce=100V and Ic=2A is well outside of the shaded area, so the transistor will likely break if you operate it under these conditions, no matter how good the cooling is.

TL;DR: These plots may look similar, but one of them shows a function Ic=f(Vce,Ib) while the other shows a different function Safe=f(Vce,Ic), which takes on the values 0 and 1.

A good datasheet will have both - one to show you how the transistor will behave, and another one to show you whether it's safe to operate the transistor like you want to.

Comment: That's the answer I was looking for for a while now. I completely didn't think Ic and Vce were independent of each other on that graph and that it showed the behaviour of Ic depending on the Vce voltage. Thanks so much for explaining this!

Answer (score 0):

The characteristic curve shows the interdependencies between the base current, collector current and collector-emitter voltages, and is mainly used to set the operating point in linear circuits to get the most linear response and the widest output range possible from a transistor.

The SOA (Safe Operating Area) curve shows the range of collector currents combined with collector-emitter voltages, in other words the maximum power that can be safely dissipated in a transistor without damaging or destroying it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an "all-in-one" plot (BJT curves and SOA for some powers).

The hyperboloid curves are used for "placing" QP at the "good" point.
Please note that temperature has some influence ...

[image]